# Convert SimpleXMLElement to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, json, loops

I have a stored procedure (SQL Server) that returns the below XML which is a top 20 ranking of search terms for a given month. 
With the following PHP I can fetch this XML and loop through it:

```
foreach ($objSearchTerms->searchTerms as $terms){ echo $terms->searchTerm; };
```

The fetching works and returns the correct data. However, my issue is that I need to create an array out of this that looks like the below to be used in JS.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this ?
The text part of the array would be my search Term (`$terms->searchTerm`) and the weight would simply be a reverse count from 20 to 0.

**My simpleXML:**

```
<ranks>
  <searchTerms>
    <rank>1</rank>
    <searchTerm>item 1</searchTerm>
    <volume>11</volume>
  </searchTerms>
  <searchTerms>
    <rank>2</rank>
    <searchTerm>item 2</searchTerm>
    <volume>8</volume>
  </searchTerms>
  <searchTerms>
    <rank>3</rank>
    <searchTerm>item 3</searchTerm>
    <volume>5</volume>
  </searchTerms>
  // ...
</ranks>
```

**The expected outcome:**

```
var word_array = [
    {text: "item 1", weight: 20},
    {text: "item 2", weight: 19},
    {text: "item 3", weight: 18},
    // ...
];
```

**I tried something like the following but this doesn't work and is probably not the right approach:**

```
$count = 21;
foreach ($objSearchTerms->searchTerms as $terms){ 
    $count--;
    echo "{text: '" . $terms->searchTerm . "', weight: " . $count . "},";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$result = [];
$count = 20;
foreach ($xml->searchTerms as $value) 
{
    $child = [];
    $child['text'] = (string)$value->searchTerm;
    $child['weight'] = $count--;
    $result[] = $child;
}
$json_string = json_encode($result);
```

The result I get with this is

```
[
    {"text":"item 1","weight":20},
    {"text":"item 2","weight":19},
    {"text":"item 3","weight":18}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Khalid and sorry - I just saw that Dreamweaver shows me an error for the line $child = []; - any though what could cause this ? Should I just write  = array() instead ?

Comment: Try to change it to `$child = Array();`

Comment: That's accepted - thanks ! How would I return the result ? print_r wouldnt work here, right ?

Comment: the result as an array of objects is in `$result`, you can try `print_r` or `var_dump` ... and if you need the result as string you'll find it in `$json_string`

Comment: Hi Khalid - thanks a lot for this and sorry for the delayed response !

Comment: how do you want it to be ? so that I can try to fix the problem